# Dictionaries in C# -- permanency of keys/values

Tags: c#

Can I keep key/items in C# code forever in my code?:

```
class Program
{
    public class Variable
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, please log in...");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your username: ");
        string y = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your passcode: ");
        string n = Console.ReadLine();
        Dictionary<String, String> usersDict = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        bool exists = usersDict.ContainsKey("n") ? usersDict["n"] == "y" : false;
        if (exists == true)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Hello; "+y);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            usersDict.Add(n, y);


            Console.WriteLine("You have been added: " + y);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So someone can make an account then another day log in??
Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Forever" is a relative term. You mean you want to keep them as long as your application hasn't terminated? Or do you also want them available between executions?

Comment: Then you need persistent storage. Perhaps the file system, or a database.

Comment: How would you use a file system and access data from it

Comment: Sidsy, you can study the [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx) or just search by "c# read write file" phrase.

Comment: Suppose someone logs in on one computer one day and from their phone another day; do you require that the information persist across devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTable would be a good alternative to a Dictionary since DataTable has handy ReadXML and WriteXML methods which allow you to write their data to a file in XML format.

Here's a method to load a Dictionary into a DataTable and write it to a file:

```
void WriteDictionaryToFile(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string filename)
    {
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dict"))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

            foreach (var kvp in dict)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
            dt.WriteXml(filename);
        }

    }
```

A method to read the a dictionary from a file:

```
void ReadDictionaryFromFile(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string filename)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dict");
    dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

    dt.ReadXml(filename);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        dict[row[0].ToString()] = row[1].ToString();
    }
}
```

These methods definitely need some exception handling added.

You could also make the methods generic by using type parameters in place of "string".  For example:

```
void ReadDictionaryFromFile<T,U>(Dictionary<T, U> dict, string filename)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dict");
    dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(T));
    dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(U));

    dt.ReadXml(filename);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        dict[(T)row[0]] = (U)row[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question would be not how you've set it up currently.

At the moment, once the program finishes with the main function, the main's stack frame will be freed, resulting in all memory being deallocated. This stands true for all programs that you run.

To get around this problem, you will need to setup a non volatile file or storage system (text files, XML documents, databases, etc) to keep the data you want to keep external from your program.

To keep things simple, I would suggest sticking to a text file until you can understand more on IO.

These links should give you a starting point:

[MSDN: How to: Write to a Text File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/8bh11f1k.aspx)

[MSDN: How to: Read from a Text File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If all that you want is to store the dictionary and retrieve it back when required, then you can do so using JSON Serialize/Deserialize . I used [Newtonsoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (available also via [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)) library below to Serialize/Deserialize.

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "1", "A" }, { "2", "B" } };

//Serialize Dictionary to string and store in file
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDictionary);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Docs\json.txt", json);

//Read serialized dictionary json string and Deserialize to Dictionary object
string jsonString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Docs\json.txt");
Dictionary<string, string> deserializedDictionary = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
```

Hope this help you...